# Two JFrame (A, B)

Tags: java

I have two `JFrame`, `A` and `B`.

A is the main JFrame, B is secondary and is invoked via a button.
Now I wish to call B, A is no longer clickable until the end of operations with B (B must remain above A until the end).

How should I do?

Comment: Do a search for ["How to make dialogs"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick draft:

1. Add Buttons to the frames A and B (for example a "done"-button to both) and add some actionlisteners to the buttons (to hide the current frame and to show an other frame for example and/or to process the actions you made)
2. Set the frame's visibility (in this case A) to false if it should be "no longer clickable" (again with actionlisteners) and the visibility of B to true.
3. If you're done with B click the "done" button of B and set the visibility of B to false and the visibility of A to true.

Comment: Or just use a modal dialog

Comment: Please, don't do it this way.  This is what modal dialogs are for.  Don't re-invent the wheel.